# How to deal with Sansung SSD NVME error on Ubuntu 20.04.2?

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, nvme

The outputs of `dmesg` is as follows:

```
[41257.315167] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: Root Port link has been reset
[41257.315201] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: device recovery successful
[41258.717662] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: Uncorrected (Fatal) error received: 0000:00:01.1
[41258.717667] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Receiver ID)
[41258.717671] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER:   device [8086:6f03] error status/mask=00000020/00000000
[41258.717673] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER:    [ 5] SDES                   (First)
[41258.717678] nvme nvme0: frozen state error detected, reset controller
[41259.779191] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: Root Port link has been reset
[41259.779225] pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: device recovery successful
```

And there are many these errors in the outputs. I'm not sure if this means the SSD disk is bad. I have to restart the system to use the SSD and it can be used just once. Then I have to restart the computer, or the system will stuck.

Could you please help give some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Odd. Have you [looked at this bug report from 2017](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195039) or so? Seems like it might be an OS issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, thanks a lot for your suggestion and comment. I've always get the system updated using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. So I thought the bug fixes would be solved in the latest Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue with a NVMe Intel, model SSDPEKNW512G8, it seems due to the NVMe inner power management which does not work well with the current kernel (OS: Kubuntu, kernel 5.13.0-35).

The laptop went freezing once a day: typically letting it ON at night, I would find it freezed at the morning.

Then, I suppose when the memory filled up a bit, started to freeze four/five times in just a morning, as well while doing stuff.

No problems at all on MSWindows.

Solved adding to the grub command line:

```
nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0
```

Current uptime with no freezes: three days and counting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

My solution: plug out the SSD card from the motherboard and then plug it in. After that, the problem seems gone.

So this might not a problem about the system or the SSD itself. Despite the problem is solved, but I still don't know how did it happen.